# How to execute a command on an S3 file

Tags: amazon-s3

I have some video files stored on S3, and I want to get video information on them using ffmpeg. However, when I do a command such as :

```
$ ffmpeg -i 'http://test.s2.amazonaws.com/video.mov
```

I get a `HTTP error 403 Forbidden` response. How would I do this command? I also want to make sure not anyone can execute stuff on these files. Thank you.

**Update**: I was able to do this after making the ACL `public-read=everyone` for the video, didn't need to use s3fs after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. You can download the file and run ffmpeg on localfile,
2. or you can use [s3fs](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon) to mount your s3 bucket as a filesystem.

Comment: The files are too big to download. Is there a way to use pre-authorized URLs OR something, or is s3fs the only way to go?

Comment: As far as i know no. if the files are too big then s3fs won't make the process faster. Maybe you can fire up an ec2 instance and run ffmpeg on it. Your instance will download the files faster and you are not going to have to pay for the bandwidth since s3 <-> ec2 transfers are free